# How to make a .desktop file show its progress in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop, sh

I have a .desktop file set to 100% upgrade my system when I double click it, and I would like to see the results of what is happening when I click it. It is basically running a shell @

```
/home/david/Update_Script
```

Which is doing

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean
```

Is there any way I could make either the .desktop or the .sh file open a terminal (Preferably an XTerm) Windows to show exactly what is happening?

Comment: Do you have Terminal=true in the .desktop file?